# Pandas DataFrame - KeyError: 'date'

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am working with a large Pandas DataFrame sourced from a JSON file.

As soon as calling specific objects of the JSON file within Pandas, I am getting key errors such as `KeyError: 'date'` for line `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`.

I have already excluded the identifier/object wording as a possible source for the error. Is there any smart tweak to make this code work?

The JSON file has the following structure:

```
[
{"stock_symbol": "AMG", "date": "2013-01-01", "txt_main": "ABC"}
]
```

And the corresponding code section looks like this:

```
import string
import json
import pandas as pd

# Loading and normalising the input file
file = open("sp500.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame().fillna("")

# Datetime conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: Remove this statement `df = pd.DataFrame().fillna("")
`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have to clean the DataFram beforehand as the `Null` values otherwise won't let the script run though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [42]: import string
    ...: import json
    ...: import pandas as pd
    ...:
    ...: # Loading and normalising the input file
    ...: #file = open("sp500.json", "r")
    ...: #data = json.load(file)
    ...: df = pd.json_normalize(a)
    ...: #df = pd.DataFrame().fillna("")
    ...:
    ...: # Datetime conversion
    ...: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
  stock_symbol       date txt_main
0          AMG 2013-01-01      ABC
```

`df = pd.DataFrame().fillna("")` creates a new empty dataframe and fills "NaN" with empty.

So, change that line to `df = df.fillna("")`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. As indicated, I however need the `fillna("")` line as the dataset includes a number of `Null` values that have to be cleaned. Is there any other approach that could work?

Comment: @M.S. Accept the answer if it has solved your question

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation examples of fillna function [fillna function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

By doing `df = pd.DataFrame().fillna("")` you are overriding your previous df with a new (empty) dataframe. You can just apply it this way: `df = df.fillna("")`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `df = pd.DataFrame().fillna("")` which will create a new dataframe and fill an with no value.
Here the old df is replaced by empty dataframe, so there is no column named **date**. Instead, you can use to fill 'na' values using `df.fillna("")`.

```
import string
import json
import pandas as pd

# Loading and normalising the input file
file = open("sp500.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = df.fillna("")

# Datetime conversion
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, the approach worked in line with the answer by user bigbounty